# Code is pulling some error "Says no line found"

Tags: java, string

Project: What’s My Name?

From the keyboard enter your first and then your last name, each with its own
prompt. Store each in a separate String and then concatenate them together to
show your full name. Call both the project and the class FullName. When your
program is finished running, the output should appear similar to that below:

`What is your first name? Cosmo
What is your last name? Kramer
Your full name is Cosmo Kramer`

---

Here is what i got:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Tester
{
public static void main(String args[])
 {
 Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in);
 String a="Cosmo";
 String b="Kramer";
 a=kbReader.nextLine();
 System.out.println("What is your first name?"+a);
 b=kbReader.nextLine();
 System.out.println("What is your last name?"+b);
System.out.println("Your full name is"+a+" "+b);
}}
```

What is wrong with my code? Both Eclipse and the web compiler doesn't work both do state a different error saying that I have no lines.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at Tester.main(Tester.java:10)
```

Comment: it is working on mine

Comment: Can you show us what your input was?

Comment: You called `nextLine()` before letting the user type anything in. Nothing has been typed into the console, so there is no line to be found by `kbReader.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be reading before you display your message,

```
String a="Cosmo";
String b="Kramer";
a=kbReader.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your first name?"+a);
b=kbReader.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your last name?"+b);
System.out.println("Your full name is"+a+" "+b);
```

and I would recommend you use descriptive variable names. So, I think you wanted something like -

```
System.out.println("What is your first name?");
String firstName = kbReader.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your last name?");
String lastName = kbReader.nextLine();
System.out.println("Your full name is " + firstName + " " + lastName);
```

Which seems to do what you asked when I run it (and provide your input) -

```
What is your first name?
Cosmo
What is your last name?
Kramer
Your full name is Cosmo Kramer
```

Finally, I note that `FullName` is not `Tester`.